# Translation using Microsoft Translator API Timeout

Tags: php, api, azure, curl, microsoft-translator

I am willing to translate a particular text in 3 different languages using  using Microsoft Translator API. I configured it and, apparently, the link I get which should drive me to translation breaks:

> `https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/MicrosoftTranslator/v1/Translate?Text=%27Osteopathy%27&From=%27en%27&To=%27nl%27&$format=Raw&$top=100`

I tried it also in my terminal with curl, with authorization, but it seems that no response is sent:

```
$ curl -H 'Authorization: Basic ***my authorization_key encoded in base64***' 'https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing                                                                                                       /MicrosoftTranslator/v1/Translate?Text=%27Osteopathy+for+Babies%27&From=%27en%27&To=%27nl%27&$format=Raw&$top=100'
```

The response from Microsoft Translator doesn't come. It simply times out.

The same piece of code worked few weeks ago.

What could be the cause? How to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried the same request as you and I do get a response back from the server but it's a 403 forbidden. I can't speculate on why the code no longer works but if you also get back a 403 it might be worth refreshing the key, it might have expired somehow. Otherwise the behaviour of the API has changed in a breaking way, it's hard to say without any official documentation.

However, you could try the Microsoft Cognitive Services API, it took be about 5 mins to setup. You will need to use OAuth bearer tokens instead of basic auth, but this is more secure anyway.

Setup docs
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/getstarted.aspx

Getting a token
http://docs.microsofttranslator.com/oauth-token.html

And some code samples
on github under MicrosoftTranslator/HTTP-Code-Samples

Comment: I added a Translator API subscription. I got 2 different access keys and a subscription ID, but I'm not which one should replace the old accountKey. I understand from your answer that I should generate an oauth-token, but I'm not sure how should I do that and where should I use that. Could you help me with it, please?

Answer (score 1):

Azure Datamarket has been closed - there is more information here about moving to Azure:
https://translatorbusiness.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/1078534-action-required-before-april-30-2017-microsoft-t

Comment: Please do not post answers that are _only_ a link to an external resource. If that link breaks, then your answer becomes invalid. Posting links to other resources is encouraged, but you should also include information in your post about relevant information from that external resource or otherwise. Please check out [This meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/360627) to learn more about why this is generally frowned upon and can be considered off-topic.

Comment: Thank you, Rosa. Indeed, the solution is to migrate Microsoft Translator API to Azure. I started this process and I hope everything will be working fine. There are a few limitations for the free account.